# unix shell script creating backup.sh

Tags: unix

How to write a shell script named "backup.sh" which accepts one parameter, which would be a filename/directory.

Create a backup copy of that with the .bak appended to its name.Show message on success.

If the file/directory does not exist, show a proper message.

i did up to this point.please help me to figure this out

```
#!/bin/sh
#create_backup.sh
And add a .bak
bak="${backup.sh}.bak"
if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]
then 
        exit 1;
    echo "File Succesfully backuped"
fi
cp ${1} "${1}.back"
echo "File is not found "
exit 0
```

Comment: turn on shell debugging with `set -vx` and you'll see right away that shells are treating `bak="${backup.sh}.bak" as you think. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash -e
directory=$1
cp -r $directory $directory.bak
echo "Success"
```

obvious caveats with pathing/error codes/etc